# RegEx for 16 characters followed by colon

Tags: regex

What would be the correct regular expression for matching strings with the following?

- Any 16 characters from the beginning of a new line.
- Followed by a colon `:`

I came up with this one but don't know if it is sufficient:
`.{16}:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the beginning of the line, [`^`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
^.{16}:
```

Answer (score 3):

The only correction I would offer is:

```
^.{16}:
```

The caret symbol (`^`) anchors to the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
^(.{16})[?=:]

. almost any character
{n} How many
[?=X] Followed by
```

Maybe is simpler ^.{16}:

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, this would be like:

`/^([^:]{16}):/m`

Some details:

`^` Line beginning

`/` Is the regexp delimiter

`[^:]` Wraps any character but `:`. I don't use "." in order to avoid problems in case you have ":" between the 16 chars. If you would like to catch it anyway, then just use "." as you are doing.

`{16}` Repeat this 16 times.

`([^:]{16})` The parentheses catch the matching value. It gets stored into a reference that can be taken by "\" or "$" later, depending on the language you're using.

`m` Here is the magic. The "m" is the **multiline modifier**. This will make the expression to be performed in every line of your text. In javascript this modifier is "g" (global).

Hope it helps!